# How to put input fields values into a contact form 7 field?

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7

I want to use

```
<input type="text" id="bla1" name="bla1" />
```

And use this input to create a field from contact form 7

```
[text bla2 id:bla2 name:bla2]
```

Maybe use some javascript to get this done?

Little update:

````
<input type="number" id="bla1" name="bla1" min="0" max="100" onblur="change(change-to-form-field);" />
  <span Method="Get" id="span2">
  [number bla2 id:bla2]
  </span>

  <script>
  function change(change-to-form-field)
{
  var bla1var = document.getElementById('bla1').value;
  document.getElementById('bla2').value=parseFloat('bla1var');
  document.span2.submit();
}
</script>
    ```
````

Comment: What do you want to use? Please add more details and rewrite your question

Comment: Sorry, i didnt use the code brackets. See edit version of the question above.

Comment: You meen from: `[text bla2 id:bla2 name:bla2]` to: `<input type="text" id="bla1" name="bla1" />`

Comment: I have found something, see the edit above. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check my example. I hope i understood you

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask the question different. How to change one input field to directly change another inputfield?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, but I want to share it. Hope I can help someone using inputfields while remaining the functionality of the Contact Form 7 fields! I ran into some problems but using the two DIV solved the issues.

```
<div name="test1">
<input type='number' id='bla1' onblur='Changeinput2field();' value="5"/>
</div>
<div name ="testarea1" Method="Get" id='form1'>
[number bla2 id:bla2 name:bla2 "5"]
</div>
<script>
function Changeinput2field()
{
  var bla1var = document.getElementById('bla1').value;
  var per10 = parseFloat(bla1var) ;
  document.getElementById('bla2').value=parseFloat(per10);
  document.form1.submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
 function CreateField(){
        var input = document.getElementById('input');
        eval('var data =' + input.value);
        var newInput = document.createElement('input')
        newInput.setAttribute('id', data.id);
        newInput.setAttribute('name', data.name);
        newInput.setAttribute('text', data.text);
        document.body.append(newInput)

        console.log(input.nodeType)
    }
```

```css
input{
width: 226px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" name="bla1" value="{text: 'bla2', id: 'bla2', name: 'bla'}" />
    <button onclick="CreateField()" title="Create Field">Create Field</button>
```

Comment: The Contact Form 7 field, between the squared brackets have certain capabilities that a normal input doesn't have. So I was planning to have two form fields which both allready have been created in Wordpress the normal input (which will be used to set the value) and the bracket formfield (which will be used to set the value to, and will be hidden). The bracket formfield could later be used to send and e-mail or to see in a database within the wordpress website.